# Get fancytree from other iframe

Tags: iframe, fancytree

I need to get fancytree instance from iframe, but trying to call

```
$(top.document).contents().find('#tree').fancytree('getTree')
```

results in error:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on fancytree prior to initialization
```

The tree is initialized and accessible from top document context. Any ideas?

Edit: iframe is on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Solved - I had to keep tree in global variable after initialization in top document:

```
tree = $('#tree').fancytree('getTree');
```

and then refer to it from iframe like this:

```
top.tree.doSth();
```